# I have different Solana balance and address with the same backup phrase imported to Phantom and TrustWallet

Tags: phantom, private-key

How is that possible?
the question is descriptive enough, but to give more context here is some history:

1. I had my backup phrase from an old multi-chain crypto wallet provider.
2. I imported that into my mobile TrustWallet in a multichain mode and I was able to see all my coins and tokens across multiple chains. but I didn't have anything in the Solana network at that time.
3. I imported the same phrase into my Chrome browser Phantom wallet extension and I started receiving some SOL and NFTs and working with it.
4. but now I noticed I don't see these SOLs or NFTs in my TrustWallet and I even have a different "Receive Solana" address

I have only one idea that might be it. I discovered that in Metamask accounts are created in order and there is a key manager for those accounts. (still not sure though if the first account is the first key generated based on the backup phrase or if it is the same key and the derived keys start from the second account.), and I think it might be the same case with the Phantom wallet for Solanad here I am working with a different key than the one considered in my TrustWallet (which is probably the exact equivalent of the backup phrase, not a derived key).

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing different pubkeys for the same seed phrase, it means that Phantom and TrustWallet are using different derivation paths to get from the seed phrases to the private key.  You can try different paths and see which ones derive the same public key, e.g.

```
solana-keygen pubkey 'prompt://?key=0/1'
solana-keygen pubkey 'prompt://?full-path=m/44/2017/0/1'
```

and once you've found the right public key, you can recover the private key using:

```
solana-keygen recover 'prompt://?full-path=m/44/2017/0/1' -o wallet.json
```

Hopefully, the wallets let you import through more than just a seed phrase or let you specify the derivation path!

More information at https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#hierarchical-derivation

Comment: Yes, I was thinking exactly the same way but didn't know how to confirm. I'll test and fiddle around with the commands you gave and I'll update here. About importing: Phantom and Metamask work the same way they only accept one seed phrase and manage derivation paths in a very simple stupid way, but let you import your own keys too. but in trustwallet I am able to import multiple phrases or keys directly, but there is no derivation path management by it at all. I'd love to have a more advanced wallet that allows both, and also enables me to create transactions with multiple inputs (UTXOs)

Answer (score 1):

Trustwallet should use m/44'/501'/0' and phantom default I think is m/44'/501'/0'/0'

So you might have to export your private key from phantom and add that to trustwallet or move your tokens